# Discord.js upload file and see progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot, and its core feature is to upload files. But, when uploading many files at once, I want to see a progress on how much it has uploaded. Is it possible? The current code looks something like this:

```
channel.send({ files: ["foo", "bar", "baz"] });
```

I couldn't find any useful information regarding Discord.js + file upload progress, only those separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to see the progress of the file upload. Normally when you send the files using the `send` function, the files should be uploaded once the `Promise` of the `send` function is fullfilled.

Comment: That makes sense, but how are users able to see it? Is it like the custom status where only users can do?